# Shortcuts on networked computer's desktop

Tags: setup-project, setup-deployment

I need my application to create shortcuts to my application on all computers connected to a particular network, when the Setup is run.
Please advise how is it possible in Setup Project.

Thanks
Furqan

Comment: A particular network is any network or it is a very specific network where you have control over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually done through separate installations:

- one on the server to install the application
- one on each client to create shortcuts and/or configuration files or registry entries

You can use a single installer for both installations, but when using Visual Studio setup projects it's easier to create separate installers.

For automation you can deploy the client installer through network deployment software, for example Active Directory (GPO). I didn't find a GPO tutorial online so I can post it here, but you can contact me if you need some guidance.